# Embedding a MatPlotLib Graph in Tkinter [.grid method], and Customizing MatPlotLib's Navigation Toolbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, graph, tkinter-canvas

I've been having problems with embedding my MatPlotLib Graph in Tkinter, and after doing some searching on Google, and the MatPlotLib website, the best I could get was the standard method:

```
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)

canvas.draw()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root) toolbar.update()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
```

Now if I try to replace the packing layout with a .grid (and remove the .pack() parameters), I get a bunch of errors, and no matter how many Google searches I have tried, all of the methods of embedding a MatPlotLib graph in Tkinter are only using the pack method. Can someone help me out with this? I want to embed the graph, but using the grid method, as the rest of the layout of my GUI application is .grid layout.

Another problem I'm having with the navigation toolbar in Tkinter is the fact that the navigation toolbar can apparently be customized (At least according to [SentDex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zw6M-BnAPP0) [5:18]). He doesn't seem to go over how I can do this, which makes it difficult for me, because I'm not very happy with MatPlotLib's buttons (They look very archaic and outdated).

Can someone please help me out with this? When I only put the graph in, it seems to work just fine, but I get issues when trying to put in the Navigation Toolbar with the graph as well. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a simple `plot` and `navigation toolbar` inside tkinter `window` using `grid` geometry manager only.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

window = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Label(window, text='A simple plot')
btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

x = ['Col A', 'Col B', 'Col C']

y = [50, 20, 80]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 5))
plt.bar(x=x, height=y)

# You can make your x axis labels vertical using the rotation
plt.xticks(x, rotation=90)

# specify the window as master
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=40, ipady=20)

# navigation toolbar
toolbarFrame = tk.Frame(master=window)
toolbarFrame.grid(row=2,column=0)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, toolbarFrame)

window.mainloop()
```

**Output GUI**

[image: plot]

I have not worked on customizing the navigation toolbar so I haven't included any solution for that part. But I'll look into it surely and update you if I find something useful. Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a simple app to control a matplotlib graph with window resizing.

I haven't used the navigation bar feature so that might be an addition to this framework

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os, json, sys
from time import time
import pandas as pd


class SliderGraph:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        # with open(self.resource_path(config_file)) as fp:
        #     self.config = json.load(fp)
        # os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = self.resource_path(creds_file)
        # self.projectID = self.config['projectID']
        # self.datasetID = self.config['datasetID']
        # last_used_freq = self.config['last_used_frequency']
        # last_used_delta = self.config['last_used_delta']

        self.bounds = 1
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.fig = Figure()
        row = 0

        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.set_xlabel("Run Numbers")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("UDD")
        self.ax.set_ylim([-self.bounds,self.bounds])

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)  # , width=win_width, height=(win_height-50))
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=row, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        row+=1

        self.table_label = tk.Label(master, text="Enter BigQuery Table Name")
        self.table_label.grid(row=row, column=0)
        # row += 1

        self.table_name = tk.Entry(master)
        # self.table_name.insert(0,self.config['last_used_table'])
        self.table_name.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='ew')
        row += 1

        self.get_table_button = tk.Button(master, text="Get Table Data and Plot", command=self.plot_data)
        self.get_table_button.grid(row=row, columnspan=2)
        row += 1

        self.frequency_slider = tk.Scale(master, from_=400, to=4500, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.update_plot)
        # self.frequency_slider.set(last_used_freq)
        self.frequency_slider.grid(row=row,columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        row += 1

        self.frequency_entry = tk.Entry(master)
        # self.frequency_entry.insert(0,last_used_freq)
        self.frequency_entry.grid(row=row, columnspan=2)
        row += 1

        self.delta_slider = tk.Scale(master, from_=-500, to=500, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.update_plot)
        # self.delta_slider.set(last_used_delta)
        self.delta_slider.grid(row=row, columnspan=2, sticky="ensw")
        row += 1

        self.delta_entry = tk.Entry(master)
        # self.delta_entry.insert(0, last_used_delta)
        self.delta_entry.grid(row=row, columnspan=2)
        row += 1

        self.get_table_button = tk.Button(master, text="Autoscale", command=self.autoscale)
        self.get_table_button.grid(row=row,columnspan=2)
        row += 1

        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(master, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(master, 1, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(master, 0, weight=5)
        for x in range(1,row):
            tk.Grid.rowconfigure(master, x, weight=0)

        master.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close)

        self.df = None
        self.frequency_list = []
        self.series = None
        self.elapsed = time()*1000

    def plot_data(self):
        self.ax.clear()
        self.client = bigquery.Client(project=self.projectID)
        self.tableID = f"`{self.datasetID}.{self.table_name.get()}`"

        QUERY = (
            f"SELECT * EXCEPT (testCount,elapsed_run_time_ms_,moleculeValue,onboardTemp1,onboardTemp2,temp,tempControl,\
             logamp, txrx,timestamp) FROM {self.tableID} ORDER BY runCount ASC;"
        )
        # query_job = self.client.query(QUERY)
        # rows = query_job.result()
        self.df = pd.read_gbq(QUERY,self.projectID)

        for col in self.df.columns:
            if 'runCount' in col:
                continue
            self.frequency_list.append(int(col.replace('_','')))
        self.frequency_slider.configure(from_=min(self.frequency_list),to=max(self.frequency_list))
        self.delta_slider.configure(from_=-max(self.frequency_list),to=max(self.frequency_list))

        freq = f'_{self.frequency_slider.get()}'
        freq2 = f'_{self.frequency_slider.get() + self.delta_slider.get()}'
        self.series = self.df[freq] - self.df[freq2]
        self.series.plot(ax=self.ax)
        self.ax.set_ylim([-self.bounds,self.bounds])

        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        self.fig.canvas.flush_events()
        pass

    def update_plot(self, newslider):
        try:

            self.ax.clear()
            freq = f'_{self.frequency_slider.get()}'
            freq2 = f'_{self.frequency_slider.get() + self.delta_slider.get()}'
            self.series = self.df[freq] - self.df[freq2]
            self.series.plot(ax=self.ax)
            zero = self.series.mean()
            self.ax.set_ylim([zero-self.bounds, zero+self.bounds])
            self.fig.canvas.draw()
            self.fig.canvas.flush_events()
            # self.master.update_idletasks()

            if ((time()*1000)-self.elapsed > 100):
                self.elapsed = time()*1000
                self.frequency_entry.delete(0,'end')
                self.frequency_entry.insert(0,freq.replace('_',''))
                self.delta_entry.delete(0,'end')
                self.delta_entry.insert(0,self.delta_slider.get())
        except:
            pass

    def play_runs(self):
        pass

    def autoscale(self):
        self.ax.clear()
        self.series.plot(ax=self.ax)
        self.ax.relim()
        self.ax.autoscale()
        zero = self.series.mean()
        self.bounds = self.series.max() - self.series.min()
        self.ax.set_ylim([zero-self.bounds,zero+self.bounds])
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        self.fig.canvas.flush_events()

    def close(self):

        self.master.destroy()

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    slider_fig = SliderGraph(root)
    root.mainloop()
```